# std::map::operator[]: инициализация при обращении к несуществующему элементу

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int a = m[0];
```

Есть ли гарантия, что a будет содержать 0? Или есть вероятность что там будет мусор?

Общий вопрос: выполняется ли инициализация простых типов(char, int, float) при чтении несуществующего элемента map? Или там будет мусор, как это происходит с объявлениями переменных без инициализации, и нужно всегда инициализировать элементы map вручную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, гарантия есть. В "классическом" С++98 поведение такого `operator[]` при новом ключе `x` описывалось как вставка элемента `make_pair(x, T())`, где `T` - тип данных map. В вашем случае это `int` и выражение `int()` порождает нулевое значение.

Начиная с С++11 спецификация `operator[]` более "запутана". Выполняется конструкция пары через `piecewise_construct` с пустым списком аргументов для второго элемента. Для типа `int` такая инициализация выливается в обнуление.

Answer (score 2):

Да, гарантирует. Выполняется инициализация значением (кажется, так она называется).

"Стандартная библиотека С++" Н. Джосаттиса, второе издание, стр. 378:

> "Если ключом является индекс, для которого не существует ни одного элемента, в отображение автоматически вставляется новый элемент. Значение нового элемента инициализируется конструктором по умолчанию для соответствующего типа. ... все элементарные типы имеют конструкторы по умолчанию, инициализирующие их значения нулями."

Из [стандарта](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4296.pdf):

> `T& operator[](const key_type& x);`
>   1 Effects: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.

И об инициализации значением оттуда же:

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>   (8.1) — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
>   (8.2) — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>   (8.3) — if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   (8.4) — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Comment: все элементарные типы имеют конструкторы по умолчанию, инициализирующие их значения нулями - Ба-тю-шки, новое слово в C++!

Comment: @gbg: Да, это утверждение формально неверно. Разумеется, у типа `int` нет никакого конструктора. Но в качестве упрощения оно встречается и в TC++PL у Страуструпа. Это что-то вроде "простительного обмана", сделанного для упрощения изложения для начинающих.

Comment: @AnT - и как потом проводить собеседование? Как доказывать джуну, у которого программа сегфолтится потому, что int не инициализирован, если вумный Страуструп позволил себе столь гениальный обман в своем учебнике?

Comment: @gbg: Я не помню всех деталей выстроенной Страуструпом "альтернативной системы". Вроде бы у него написано, что у скалярных типов есть конструкторы, но их всегда надо "вызывать явно" или что-то в этом роде... То есть `int()` и `int i{};` - это гарантированные нули, а вот `int i;` ничего не гарантирует. Понятно, что эта "альтернативная система" противоречит стандарту, но сразу вываливать на новичка всю разветвленную и навороченную систему правил инициализации С++ тоже не хочется.

Comment: @gdb Знаете, даже спорить не хочется. Можете считать, что "гарантии нет и будет мусор" - такое допущение немного усложнит программу, но отнюдь не испортит :) И все же, скажите интереса для - что вернет вызов `ret<int>()` для `template<class T> T ret() { return T(); }` - мусор?

Comment: Значит, что фактически имеем. Первый автор, на которого вы сослались, говорит нам чудесную вещь, что якобы в C++ у примитивных типов есть конструкторы. Это - сильное заявление. Фактически же, у примитивных типов есть какие-то инициализаторы, которые случаются в некоторых описанных в стандарте случаях (о чем я не знал, пока не начал разбираться в вопросе более подробно). Но я в данном случае возбудился именно на пассаж про конструкторы у примитивных типов.

Comment: @gbg, да, у встроенных типов нет конструкторов, но  Harry просто хотел ответить попроще, но не вышло. Но и у вас не вышло быть повежливее, и вместо того, чтоб возмущаться, просто предупредить   об этом

Comment: вопрос довольно простой, и дискуссировать не о чем

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это да... Но просто что-то разозлил минус за верный ответ :), тем более что про конструкторы даже не сам писал, а просто Джосаттиса цитировал...